# Inverse of an operator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, fermions, greens-functions, propagator

I want to understand how to find the Inverse of an operator.
I know it involves the use of Green's function but I can't seem to figure out how.

Here is the actual problem:

On page 302 of Peskin&Schroeder (last paragraph of the subsection **The Dirac propagator** of the section **9.5**), we have
$$\langle0|T\psi(x)\bar{\psi}(y)|0\rangle = [-i(i\not{\partial} - m)]^{-1}.\tag{1}$$

Evaluating this inverse in Fourier space, we find the result for the Feynman Propagator,
$$\langle0|T\psi(x)\bar{\psi}(y)|0\rangle = \int \frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4} e^{-ik(x-y)} \frac{i}{(\not{k} - m + i\epsilon)}.\tag{9.72}$$

I want to know how to find the inverse of an operator using Fourier transformation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Spin_1%E2%81%842

Answer (score 2):

The inverse of an operator $A$ has the same eigenfunctions as $A$, but has inverse eigenvalues. Most of the operators that you find in free field theory are Hermitian and are diagonalized by the Fourier modes, so to compute their inverse you can simply compute their action on a Fourier mode $e^{ikx}$ and then divide by the associated eigenvalue instead of multiplying. For instance in the case of the operator $\partial_\mu \partial^\mu + m^2$, which shows up for a massive scalar field, we have $(\partial_\mu \partial^\mu + m^2) e^{ipx} = (m^2 - p^2) e^{ipx}$. Thus, $(\partial_\mu \partial^\mu + m^2)^{-1} e^{ipx} = \frac{e^{ipx}}{(m^2 - p^2)}$. To then reconstruct the action of the operator $(\partial_\mu \partial^{\mu} + m^2)^{-1}$ on a field $\psi(x)$, we can project $\psi$ onto the operator's eigenbasis by taking the Fourier transform, scale by the associated eigenvalue, and then project back via the inverse Fourier transform. This procedure gives you your standard expression for the propagator of a free boson.

The procedure is essentially identical for the fermionic case, as explained in the article linked in the comment. The crucial point is that these operators are translationally invariant and thus diagonalizable in the Fourier basis-- were this not the case you would not get such clean expressions in terms of Fourier transforms.

The Green's function approach is quite similar but proceeds via the intermediate step of finding the solution to $({\partial}\!\!\!/ - m)^{-1} G = -\delta$. This equation can also be readily solved in Fourier space by noting that the Fourier transform of $\delta$ is trivial- just $\hat{\delta}(p) \sim 1$.